# lightning navigation pass parameters in URL

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

on my custom community page, using a Lighting web component and navigating to a different page by passing some query string in URL, problem is the unable to refer Javascript variable in below code snippet:

```
let keyVal;
let val;
// here this.params is having a value like "tabset=e2571"

if(this.params && this.params.split('=').length === 2){
  keyVal = this.params.split('=')[0];
  val = this.params.split('=')[1];
}

this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
  type: 'comm__namedPage',
  attributes: {
    pageName: 'samplePage'

  },
  state: {
    keyVal : val
  }
});
```

This code is not able to refer the value of keyVal variable and ended up to generate below URL:
**Actual URL:**
https://xxxx.cs151.force.com/xxxxx/s/samplePage?keyVal=e2571

**Expected URL**
https://xxxx.cs151.force.com/xxxxx/s/samplePage?tabset=e2571

I have already tried with replacing the variable name with c__keyVal but no luck.

Comment: I am curious if this is actually working for you in Community since [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation/documentation) says that state is not supported for PageReference in Lightning communities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because when you declare a state object like this:

```
state: {
    keyVal : val
  }
```

you do not use `keyVal` variable, you just declare a new property of the state object.

One of possible solutions would be to create an object and assign its properties like this:

```
var obj = {};
obj[keyVal] = val;
```

and then you can assign this object to the state object:

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
  type: 'comm__namedPage',
  attributes: {
    pageName: 'samplePage'

  },
  state: obj
});
```